# How to make typescript optional for ionic 2 applications?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

If I need to import a new JS library in an Angular component of an ionic 2 application i first need to install types via typings.

I thought typescript was optional for ionic 2.

How do I need to configure Ionic 2 to skip this additional step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that a few weeks ago I asked that in `ionic-v2` Slack channel and the answer from one developer of Ionic Team was:

> We're going all in on TS.
>
> You could do your own work and covert it toa es6 workflow, but we want
> people to use typescript

So Typescript **is not optional** for Ionic 2 applications.

---

**UPDATE:**

There's also an *All in on TypeScript* section in [Ionic2 resource pages](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/typescript/) where Ionic Team explains the benefits of using TypeScript:

> TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript that gives you advantages like:
>
> - Optional static typing (the key here is optional)
> - Type Inference, which gives some of the benefits of types, without actually using them
> - Access to ES6 and ES7 features, before they become supported by major
>   browsers
> - The ability to compile down to a version of JavaScript that
>   runs on all browsers
> - Great tooling support with IntelliSense
>
> Because of these awesome features and the huge advantages it gives to you as a
> developer, **Ionic 2 apps are written in TypeScript, instead of ES6**.